# Define <li> Anchors Width

Tags: html, css, menu, width

I'm struggling with an inline menu. I cant create a defined size for my `<li><a ...></a></li>` links / anchors.

I want them to have a specific size because I want to have a hover effect, an image background.

This is my code: [PREVIEW](http://styleeuclides.site50.net/)

Any guidance will be a really great help! I'll be really appreciated

Comment: Please copy HTML and CSS code here. There are two reasons: 1. your question can help future viewers 2. It's easier for us to help. In addition your site is behind some mix of iframe/javascript so to browse your code we need to use firebug etc.

Comment: Sorry, since I was testing online, didnt felt the need to copy the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I understand, you have to define your anchor tags as blocks, for instance:

```
li > a {
display: block;
}
```

you can also use "inline-block".
Then, you will be able to define it "width" and "height".

Comment: Also, if it's an inline menu, you might need to define "float: left" to your list items.